# Enable pretty printing in Eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, debugging, gdb

I am trying to enable pretty printing for STL in Eclipse. These are my versions:

- Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
- gdb 7.11.1
- Xubuntu 16.04
- gcc 7.4.0
- g++ 7.4.0

I have read various guides and this is what I did (I copied the answers from other SO qns):

STEP 1: Download the pretty printers:

```
$ cd /home/ali/Downloads
$ svn co svn://gcc.gnu.org/svn/gcc/trunk/libstdc++-v3/python
```

STEP 2: Edit gdbinit

```
$ subl /home/ali/.gdbinit
```

Paste the following in .gdbinit:

```
python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, '/home/ali/Downloads/python/')
from libstdcxx.v6.printers import register_libstdcxx_printers
register_libstdcxx_printers (None)
end
```

I have also tried the one that comes with gcc, that is:

```
sys.path.insert(0, '/usr/bin/gcc-8/python')
```

Also, I have added the lines to printers.py:

```
if length > 100: length = 100
```

STEP 3: Setup Eclipse

In the GDB settings for Eclipse (Window->Preferences->C/C++->Debug->GDB), set the GDB command file path to the .gdbinit file you just created. Also, in the same tab, check the box for Pretty Printing.

For any existing debug configurations (Run->Debug Configurations) which require pretty-printing, select the debug configuration, then set the GDB command file path on the Debugger tab.

STEP 4: Testing GDB

You can verify that GDB is pretty-printing as follows (once the first two steps of the previous procedure have been completed):

Save the following code in a file named test.cpp:

```
#include <map>
int main() {
std::map<char, int> first;
first['a'] = 10;
first['b'] = 20;
}
```

Compile with g++:

```
$ g++ -g -o test test.cpp
```

Run gdb:

```
$ gdb test
```

Set a break point:

```
(gdb) b test.cpp:5
```

This will output:

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x40093f: file src/test.cpp, line 5.
```

Run the program:

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /path/to/test
```

When the break point is hit, the gdb prompt will be displayed. Print the map with the following command:

```
(gdb) p first
```

If all is well, you should see the following output:

```
$1 = std::map with 1 elements = {[97 'a'] = 10}
```

I still do not get pretty printing in Eclipse (its working fine using gdb in Terminal):

```
seq_of_probs = {<No data fields>}}
Default:{...}
Decimal:{...}
Hex:{...}
Binary:{...}
Octal:{...}
```

where seq_of_probs is of type `std::vector<std::string>`

Could someone please suggest any steps that is missing or wrong? I have been trying for a day now.

Things off my mind:

Does DSF-GDB or CDI-GDB matter? I do not know which one my Eclipse is using.

In Eclipse, my default gdb debugger is gdb. I changed it to usr/bin/gdb. Either way, both didn't work.

Is the gdb that my Eclipse is using python-enabled? My gdb version should be python-enabled. Or is there another binary for that?

Edit:

Now I am getting this error:

Multiple errors reported.

1) Failed to execute MI command:

```
-var-create - * state
Error message from debugger back end:
Cannot instantiate printer for default visualiser
```

2) Unable to create variable object

3) Failed to execute MI command:

```
-var-create - * state
Error message from debugger back end:
Cannot instantiate printer for default visualiser
```

state is a vector.

**UPDATE:**

So I think pretty printing is working in Eclipse when I am using gcc 4.8 and g++ 4.8. This is what I got:

```
Name : test
Details:std::vector of length 3, capacity 4 = {1, 2, 3}
Default:{...}
Decimal:{...}
Hex:{...}
Binary:{...}
Octal:{...}

Name : [0]
Details:N/A (child of pretty-printed object)
Default:1
Decimal:1
Hex:0x1
Binary:1
Octal:01
```

I hope this provide further clues to what needs to be fixed. Any ideas?