# Pretty printing in Eclipse C++ works for some projects and doesn't for others

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I have enabled pretty printing for Eclipse-CDT. This is my previous question: [Enable pretty printing in Eclipse C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56585630/enable-pretty-printing-in-eclipse-c)

I have done all the steps as mentioned in my previous question. I realized that pretty printing does work for a simple test program but doesn't work on my projects. Hence, I am opening a new question as this seems to be project-specific settings.

This is my setup:

- Eclipse Version: 2018-09 (4.9.0)
- gdb 7.11.1
- Xubuntu 16.04
- gcc 7.4.0
- g++ 7.4.0

I have a simple test.cpp

```
#include <map>
#include<vector>

int main() {
    std::map<char, int> first;
    first['a'] = 10;
    first['b'] = 20;
    std::vector<int> a{1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

I import this into Eclipse using New > Makefile Project with Existing Code, compile it in terminal:
    g++ -g -o test test.cpp

I then debug this program in Eclipse and got this:

```
Name : first
    Details:std::map with 1 element = {[97 'a'] = 10}
    Default:{...}
    Decimal:{...}
    Hex:{...}
    Binary:{...}
    Octal:{...}
```

So pretty printing works in Eclipse-CDT for this simple test case. I am assuming whatever settings in Eclipse > Windows > Preferences are set up fine.

For my other two projects (one of which is using https://github.com/Svalorzen/AI-Toolbox), I paste the code snippet in test.cpp into the main.cpp, compile it using make with project-specific CMakeLists in Eclipse, debug it and got this:

For one of the projects:

```
Name : first
    Details:{_M_t = {_M_impl = {<No data fields>}}}
    Default:{...}
    Decimal:{...}
    Hex:{...}
    Binary:{...}
    Octal:{...}
```

For the other project:

```
Multiple errors reported.

1) Failed to execute MI command:
-var-create - * first
Error message from debugger back end:
Null value returned for children

2) Unable to create variable object

3) Failed to execute MI command:
-var-create - * first
Error message from debugger back end:
Null value returned for children
```

I have checked the Debug Configuration > Debugger for all 3 cases and the settings are the same. Does anyone have any idea why am I getting these errors?

I am guessing that I might need to modify the CMakeLists but I do not have sufficient knowledge to figure this out. This is the snippet of my CMakeLists for both projects:

```
set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE "Debug")
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)
```

The full CMakeLists is here https://github.com/Svalorzen/AI-Toolbox/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

Answer (score 0):

So after fiddling with CMakeLists, I figured out the offending line that disables pretty printing:

`set_target_properties(lib PROPERTIES INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION ${LTO_SUPPORTED})`

Removing this line will make pretty printing work. I changed it to this instead and build in debug mode.

```
IF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
    set_target_properties(lib PROPERTIES INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION ${LTO_SUPPORTED})
ENDIF(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE MATCHES Release)
```